# Is there any way to ungroup the groupby dataframe with adding an additional column

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, group-by

Suppose we take a pandas dataframe...

```
    item  MRP     sold
0   A     10       10
1   A     36       4
2   B     32       6
3   A     26       7
4   B     30       9
```

Then do a `groupby('item').mean()`

it becomes

```
   item  MRP     sold
0   A     24      7
1   B     31      7.5
```

Is there a way to retain the mean values of MRP, of all the unique items and make another column which will contain those values when ungrouped.

Basically what i want is

```
    item  MRP     sold  Mean_MRP
0   A     10       10    24
1   A     36       4     24
2   B     32       6     31
3   A     26       7     24
4   B     30       9     31
```

There are a lot of items, so i need a faster and optimised way to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) function :

```
df = (df
      .assign(Mean_MRP = lambda x:x.groupby('item')['MRP']
                                   .transform('mean')))

df


  item  MRP     sold    Mean_MRP
0   A   10      10       24
1   A   36      4        24
2   B   32      6        31
3   A   26      7        24
4   B   30      9        31
```

You could also use the [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.groupby_agg.html#janitor.groupby_agg) module, which makes the code a bit cleaner:

```
import janitor

df.groupby_agg(by='item',
               agg='mean',
               agg_column_name="MRP",
               new_column_name='Mean_MRP')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `transform`:

```
df['Mean_MRP'] = df.groupby('item').transform('mean')
```